# Multiple Subsitutions in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. I have two tables and I would like to substitute a code for a full name in two columns.

Table 1: scores

```
+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| h_team | a_team | gamedate   | gametime | spread | h_score | a_score | timeremaining | currentwinner |
+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+
| NE     | PIT    | 2015-09-10 | 8:30 PM  |      0 |      28 |      21 | 00:00         | NULL          |
| CHI    | GB     | 2015-09-13 | 1:00 PM  |      0 |       0 |       0 | PreGame       | NULL          |
| HOU    | KC     | 2015-09-13 | 1:00 PM  |      0 |       0 |       0 | PreGame       | NULL          |
| NYJ    | CLE    | 2015-09-13 | 1:00 PM  |      0 |       0 |       0 | PreGame       | NULL          |
| BUF    | IND    | 2015-09-13 | 1:00 PM  |      0 |       0 |       0 | PreGame       | NULL          |
| WAS    | MIA    | 2015-09-13 | 1:00 PM  |      0 |       0 |       0 | PreGame       | NULL          |

+--------+--------+------------+----------+--------+---------+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

Table 2: teamnames

```
+------+---------------+
| abbr | shortname     |
+------+---------------+
| ARI  | Arizona       |
| ATL  | Atlanta       |
| BAL  | Baltimore     |
```

Is is possible to replace both `h_team` and `a_team` from `scores` with the `shortname` from `teamnames`? I keep finding ways of just replacing one of the other.

Here is what I have that's closest:

```
SELECT b.shortname AS short_h, b.shortname, a.a_team, a.gametime, a.h_score, a.a_score 
FROM week1_live a, nfl_teams b 
WHERE b.abbr=a.h_team OR b.abbr=a.a_team 
ORDER BY a.gamedate, a.gametime;
```

But this is what I get:

`+---------------+---------------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
| short_h       | shortname     | a_team | gametime | h_score | a_score |
+---------------+---------------+--------+----------+---------+---------+
| New England   | New England   | PIT    | 8:30 PM  |      28 |      21 |
| Pittsburgh    | Pittsburgh    | PIT    | 8:30 PM  |      28 |      21 |
| Carolina      | Carolina      | CAR    | 1:00 PM  |       0 |       0 |
| Houston       | Houston       | KC     | 1:00 PM  |       0 |       0 |`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT b.shortname AS short_a, c.shortname AS short_h, a.gametime, a.h_score, a.a_score 
FROM week1_live a
inner join nfl_teams b on b.abbr=a.a_team 
inner join nfl_teams c on c.abbr=a.h_team 
ORDER BY a.gamedate, a.gametime;
```

Comment: Brilliant! I did not realize you could do inner joins with MySQL and twice for that matter. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You should join two times (as there are two relations between the tables)

```
select H.shortname, A.shortname, S.gamedate, .....
from scores S
left join teamnames H on (H.abbr = S.h_team)
left join teamnames A on (A.abbr = S.a_team)
order by ...
```

one time you join for h_team and the second one for a_team.
left join is for cases when a_team or h_team are not present in the teamnames table. in this case you should get null in the shortname